# Why can't my own library be imported in my project?

Tags: python, python-import

I do have a simple python project. It is structured as follows:

```
C:\projects\python\Testovnik>tree
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is BC5F-5E5E
C:.
├───.vscode
│   └───.ropeproject
├───Testovnik
│   ├───lib
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───questions
└───tests
```

Now in the `tests` directory I have this file:

`question_tests.py`

```
import unittest

from Testovnik.lib.question import Question
from Testovnik.lib.question_file import QuestionFile

test_file = '..\\questions\\002.txt'


class TestQuestion(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_question(self):
        question_file = QuestionFile(test_file)
        self.assertEqual(question_file.get_question, 'Pisior?')

    def test_answers_length(self):
        question_file = QuestionFile(test_file)
        self.assertEqual(len(question_file.get_answers()), 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I want to import two classes: `Question` and `QuestionFile` which are both located accordingly in: `Testovnik\lib\question.py` and `Testovnik\lib\question_file.py`

When I run `python question_tests.py` it throws me this:

```
C:\projects\python\Testovnik\tests>python question_tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "question_tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Testovnik.lib.question import Question
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Testovnik
```

My question is what path should I put there to make it work?

@Edit This is my project structure with all the files (`__init__.py` files are empty):

[image]

Comment: do you have a __init__.py file?

Comment: Add an empty `__init__.py` file in each one of your sub directories.

Comment: `import sys` and print `sys.path` before and after `import` to inspect what you have and where you have it.

Comment: I guess I have them, look, I've updated the question

Comment: remove `__init__.py` from your tests folder

Comment: Removed `__init__.py`, the same error

Comment: that's recommended anyway. [https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#goodpractices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#goodpractices)

Comment: try `C:\projects\python\Testovnik> python -m pytest tests/question_tests.py`

Comment: It throws this: `ImportError while importing test module 'C:\projects\python\Testovnik\tests\question_tests.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests\question_tests.py:3: in <module>
    from Testovnik.lib.question import Question
Testovnik\lib\question.py:2: in <module>
    from lib.answer import Answer
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.25 seconds ===========================`

Comment: replace imports with `from lib.question import Question` and `from lib.question_file import QuestionFile` and try again

Comment: What do you mean by replacing?

Comment: strip the `Testovnik.` prefix. I have the same structure like you and it works for me.

Comment: Still the same, both for standard `python question_tests.py` and `python -m pytest tests/question_tests.py`

Comment: Ah no, I missread your structure. But you have no `__init__.py` right under `Testovnik` thats why it doesn't search further in `lib`. Stay with your original imports but add one `__init__` in the same directory along the `lib` folder.

Comment: But there is an `__init__.py`: https://imgur.com/a/wFWW5

Comment: Damn you're right. Then I'm pretty much out of ideas. Last guess would be don't name two directories `Testovnik`, maybe that confuses things.

Comment: Look at this guys structure: `https://github.com/localstack/localstack`. It's the same as mine and he actually has the `localstack/localstack` directory, so I guess it's not that

Comment: Wait, watch your traceback you posted above. `from lib.answer import Answer`. Does question import from answer? This seems to cause the error not that pytest couldn't find Question.

Comment: Yes it does. But I changed my `question_tests.py` and it still doesnt work:

https://imgur.com/a/HPASx

Comment: And how do your imports look like in `question.py`?

Comment: `from random import random
from lib.answer import Answer`

Comment: Now your version works, I mean calling it with the `python -m pytest`

Comment: What did you try before then? That's what I was expecting you to do all the time

Comment: I did test with `python question_tests.py` being in `tests` dir. Now I ran that command but being above `tests`

Comment: Yeah that can't work and it shouldn't for safety reasons. Think you can find the reasoning behind that in the link I posted above.

Comment: So I should always run it from like project root?

Comment: Yes pytest will put this together then. But read the link, I'm no expert for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()), r'Testovnik\lib')
from question import Question
from question_file import QuestionFile

#...#
```

Comment: Do I need to do that everytime? Cuz in this git repo: `https://github.com/localstack/localstack` the author imports `from localstack.services.awslambda import lambda_api, lambda_executors` in `localstack/tests/unit/test_lambda.py` which seems to be exact same structure as mine

Comment: When you print out your `sys.path`, what are there? If one of the path can eventually lead to your `Testovnik\lib` directory then it *should* work already.  But otherwise you can just add that line to your `question_test.py`.  Better way would be update the path to be dynamic.

Comment: It prints this after executing your `sys.path.append()`: https://imgur.com/a/OaDEZ

Comment: Yup, if you notice, before you appended the the `lib` path, there's not one path that goes to `C:\projects\python\` so when you try to import from `Testovnik` it wouldn't work.  When you add this snippet to your code, does it work though?

Comment: Nope, it still does not

Comment: What error are you getting now though? Is it still `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Testovnik`? In theory you now have the `lib` path in your `sys.path` so it should be able to locate `question.py` and `question_file.py`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163984/discussion-between-idlehands-and-frynio).